# Encoder[Row] in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to perform a simple map on a `Dataset[Row]` (`DataFrame`) in Spark 2.0.0.  Something as simple as this

```
val df: DataSet[Row] = ...
df.map { r: Row => r }
```

But the compiler is complaining that I'm not providing the implicit `Encoder[Row]` argument to the map function:

> not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$7:
>   Encoder[Row]).

Everything works fine if I convert to an RDD first `ds.rdd.map { r: Row => r }` but shouldn't there be an easy way to get an `Encoder[Row]` like there is for tuple types `Encoders.product[(Int, Double)]`?

[Note that my `Row` is dynamically sized in such a way that it can't easily be converted into a strongly-typed `Dataset`.]

Answer (score 1):

An `Encoder` needs to know how to pack the elements inside the `Row`. So you could write your own `Encoder[Row]` by using `row.structType` which determines the elements of your `Row` at runtime and uses the corresponding decoders.

Or if you know more about the data that goes into `Row`, you could use https://github.com/adelbertc/frameless/

Answer (score 1):

SSry to be a "bit" late. Hopefully this helps to someone who is hitting the problem right now. Easiest way to define encoder is deriving the structure from existing DataFrame:

```
val df = Seq((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c").toDF("id", "name")
val myEncoder = RowEndocer(df.schema)
```

Such approach could be useful when you need altering existing fields from your original DataFrame.

If you're dealing with completely new structure, explicit definition relying on `StructType` and `StructField` (as suggested in @Reactormonk 's little cryptic response).

Example defining the same encoder:

```
val myEncoder2 = RowEncoder(StructType(
  Seq(StructField("id", IntegerType), 
      StructField("name", StringType)
  )))
```

Please remember `org.apache.spark.sql._`, `org.apache.spark.sql.types._` and `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder` libraries have to be imported.

Comment: Instead of `RowEncoder(df.schema)` you can simply use `df.encoder`.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case where the mapped function does not change the schema, you can pass in the encoder of the DataFrame itself:

```scala
df.map(r => r)(df.encoder)
```